# How to get the key of an element in firebase with AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, key, observable, angularfire2

I am displaying a table of products in my Angular project, it displays just fine but the link which I want in the format **/admin/products/key** doesnt work. I have come to the conclussion that the `p.$key` isnt showing the key:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
            <td>{{ p.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.price }}</td>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.$key]">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**p.$key** value is undefined, does someone knows how to fix it?

Ps: If anyone needs to know the value of `products$`, it is equal to `this.products$ = this.productService.getAll().valueChanges();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the idField property inside of valueChanges like this:

`this.productService.getAll().valueChanges({idField: '$key'});`

Then the firebase id will be available within your object like this:
`p.$key`

Also, consider using the json pipe like `{{ p | json }}` for development and you can see all of the values in the object in your browser.